# JavaFx - binding MapProperty key set to SetProperty

Tags: java, javafx

I have two properties:

```
SetProperty<String> set
```

and

```
MapProperty<String, Map<String, String>> map
```

My question is how to bind keyset of this map property to set property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `SetBinding` class yourself that listens to changes in the `ObservableMap`:

```
public class MapKeyBinding<K> extends SetBinding<K> {

    private final ObservableSet<K> readonlyView;

    public <V> MapKeyBinding(ObservableMap<K, V> map) {
        ObservableSet<K> set = FXCollections.observableSet();
        set.addAll(map.keySet());
        readonlyView = FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableSet(set);
        map.addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends K, ? extends V> change) -> {
            if (change.wasAdded() != change.wasRemoved()) {
                if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                    set.remove(change.getKey());
                } else {
                    set.add(change.getKey());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected ObservableSet<K> computeValue() {
        return readonlyView;
    }

}
```

#### Use

```
ReadOnlySetProperty<String> set = new ReadOnlySetWrapper(new MapKeyBinding(map)).getReadOnlyProperty();
```

Note that using a `SetProperty` here is not really necessary, since you can use a `ObservableSet`:

```
ObservableSet<String> set = new MapKeyBinding(map);
```

However, if you insist on replacing the `ObservableSet` every time the `Map` is modified, you can use a the bindings API for that:

```
 set.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> new MapKeyBinding<>(map.get()), map));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should expose it as a ReadOnlySetProperty instead of a full SetProperty, since a Map's keySet cannot be replaced:

```
ReadOnlySetProperty<String> set = new ReadOnlySetWrapper(
    FXCollections.observableSet(map.keySet())).getReadOnlyProperty();
```

Comment: It seems to me that in this case you created ReadOnlyPropertySet from java.util.Set and it isn't binded with map's keys. Am I right?

Comment: It is backed by the Map’s keySet, but if “bind” means listeners getting invoked whenever the Map is modified, then you’re correct;  it’s not a true binding.